# Spell Selection on Lore Seeker campaign Trait

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells

On page 331 of the Pathfinder Advanced Players Guide, there is the lore seeker trait that has the following:

> If you cast arcane spells, pick three spells on your spell list. You are particularly adept at casting these spells, so they function at +1 caster level when you cast them, and tier save DCs (if any)gain a +1 bonus.

Does this mean that the player must already be able to cast the spell (limiting to 0 and 1st level spells) or can the three spells be chosen at a later date (or even chosen then, to be learned later)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Neither! The trait says pick three spells on your spell *list*, not in your spell book. A character's spell list includes spells they can't cast yet - "fireball" is on a first level wizard's spell list. So you can pick spells you can't cast yet, but you have to make the selection when you take the trait.